# Substracting rasters by minimum values (loop over list) using R

Tags: raster, r, reclassify

I'm trying to reclassify a bunch of rasters by substracting the pixels of each of them with their minimum value (eg: I want to substract all the pixels of a raster(A) by its minimum value, same thing for raster(B), (C) etc...).
It was not a problem to do such task in QGIS when I only had a few ones but now that I have more than 200 rasters I don't have other choice than automating the process.

Here is my script so far:

```
library(raster)

mypath <- "F:/Stage/Modele_SIG/Etape_2/test/"

files <- list.files(mypath, pattern="*tif$")

rasters <- lapply(paste0(mypath, files), raster)

for (i in 1:length(rasters)) {
  r <- rasters[[i]]
  r <- r - cellStats(r, "min")
  r <- writeRaster(r, files[i], overwrite=TRUE)
}

r
```

Unfortunately it seems that only one of my rasters is fetched in `rasters[i]` when the loop is run whereas I have all my rasters in `rasters`

How do I make my script work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
rasters <- lapply(paste0(mypath, files), raster)
```

which makes `rasters` a list of raster objects. Then you do:

```
for (i in 1:length(rasters)) {
  r <- raster(rasters[[i]])
```

which is calling `raster(...)` on a raster object (`rasters[[i]]`).

That creates a new uninitialised raster.

You probably just want to do `r <- rasters[[i]]` there.

Once you get past that then this won't work either:

```
r <- writeRaster(r, rasters[i], overwrite=TRUE)
```

because `rasters[i]` is not a file name. You need to index into `files[i]` to get the file name.